# How do you change an IP address in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, networking

I need to do a number of network-related things in C++ that I would normally do with `ifconfig` in Linux, but I'd like to do it without parsing the output of a group of system calls.  Which C or C++ libraries can I use to tell if a network adapter is up or down, read or change an adapter's IP address and netmask, and change the default DNS gateway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you need to make a bunch of ioctl calls using a socket handle (SIOCGIFADDR, SIOCADDRT). You can find sample programs that use it in the Linux kernel source under Documentation/networking. Some other links that might be helpful:

- [Network Interface operations on AIX](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-ioctl-socket.html)
- [XBMC's implementation](http://xbmc.org/trac/browser/branches/linuxport/XBMC/xbmc/linux/NetworkLinux.cpp) (check out CNetworkInterfaceLinux)

EDIT: Let me also add that if your target is desktop linux, then you can consider using the DBUS API to query network parameters using the NetworkManager.

- http://people.redhat.com/dcbw/NetworkManager/NetworkManager DBUS API.txt (sorry there's some issue inserting links in edits)

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up using ioctl, which I found out about through the first link you provided.

Answer (score 4):

You can always look at ifconfig's source code to see how they did it in the first place: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/net-tools/net-tools_1.60.orig.tar.gz

Comment: Thanks.  I'll keep that in mind next time I'm trying to re-invent the wheel.  :)

Comment: + because I love poeple who are digging inside the sources!

Answer (score 0):

The [NetworkManager](http://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/) service exposes an API over [dbus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus) for querying/manipulating the networking on many distributions these days. This may be too high-level for your purposes (e.g. you require finer control of the network, or dbus/NetworkManager are not available on the system...), but it may provide you with what you need.

Check out the [dbus C++ bindings](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus-c%2B%2B) and the [NetworkManager API](http://people.redhat.com/dcbw/NetworkManager/NetworkManager%20DBUS%20API.txt) (sorry, I can't find a better formatted version right now, but the information is there).