# How to set IP to network interface?

Tags: c++, networking, ip

I want to set IP to each network interface in my PC. I use following command that I call from my C++ code.

```
netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" static ipaddr subnetmask gateway metric
```

Because `netsh` needs adapter's name I used `GetAdaptersInfo` to get all adapters. The problem is that `GetAdaptersInfo` returns name as GUID and not as, for example, "Local Area Connection 4" that is what `netsh` requires.

My questions are:

1. Can I set ip according to MAC and not "Local Area Connection"?
2. If (1) is cannot be done, so how to convert `GetAdaptersInfo->AdapterName` which is GUID to "Local Area Connection"?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378808/how-do-you-change-an-ip-address-in-c

Comment: This is not a duplicate! How the your link and my post are the same? Did you even read my post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to get the friendly name that can be passed to `netsh`. As [this](http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancediphelperfunction13h.html) post says we need to use `GetAdaptersAddresses` and not `GetAdaptersInfo`.